# TypeError: 'int object has no attribute '__getitem__' ... but where?

Tags: python, typeerror

For a Markov chain project I am writing, I am generating the error at the top of the page. I know that this means I am trying to call a list method on an integer object, which must means I am either a) not initializing a list correctly or b) overwriting a list with an integer value at some point in the program. However, I have been trying to debug this for hours now and cannot find the issue in my small program. The error trace is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/adamlind/PycharmProjects/Capstone/Song.py", line 9, in <module>
    musicMarkov.add(["c", 4]) #row
  File "/Users/adamlind/PycharmProjects/Capstone/Music.py", line 19, in add
    self._markov.add(iNote[0], fNote[0])
  File "/Users/adamlind/PycharmProjects/Capstone/Markov.py", line 22, in add
    self._adjMatrix[val[iVal]][val[fVal]] += 1
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

And here is a link to the GitHub repo containing my project (this is my first StackOverflow question, not sure if this is frowned upon or not):
https://github.com/adamlind323/CSC493

I checked through a few times but couldn't figure out where I am overwriting. I'm not very experienced with Python, so any and all help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Either `val` or `_adjMatrix` is an `int`, probably `val`

Comment: In this line `val = self._lookupVal[iVal]`, because the _lookupVal is a dict, we can know that val is an int. And in this line: `self._adjMatrix[val[iVal]][val[fVal]] += 1`, you use it as a list.

Comment: *"not sure if this is frowned upon or not"* - the latter, please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`val` is int. Attempt to index (`val[iVal]`) leads to exception.

On line #21 you intialize `val` in the following way:

```
val = self._lookupVal[iVal]
```

`_lookupVal` is a dictionary defined on line #11 which contains integers (see line #14)

Comment: I see now, thanks! Deleted [iVal] and everything works perfectly. I appreciate the help.